Copy and Paste from OneNote adds garbage invisible characters
I've been using OneNote (within Linux Chrome browser) to store notes.  I'll often put Linux commands that I've used to record how to install something, etc.
I recently found that when I'm pasting a command from OneNote the characters pasted include some garbage characters that are invisible, so the command looks normal but doesn't run.
For example,
history | grep altern
  509  sudo update-alternatives --list java 
  549  sudo update-alternatives --list java

Running command !509 fails:
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java 

Running what appears to be the same command !549 works.
!549
sudo update-alternatives --list java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

I've tracked the problem down and found that invisible characters are pasted which result in an invalid command.  I can detect this with cat -v as shown next:
history|grep alternatives|cat -v
  509  sudo update-alternatives --list javaM-BM- 
  557  sudo update-alternatives --list java

I'm not sure what -BM- is so I called this garbage characters.
My question is Is there a simple way I can copy/paste from OneNote and strip the garbage characters?
Searching for a solution
I was surprised that I didn't find a solution (hence my post)... Some posts that were similar are listed below.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-do-strange-characters-appear-when-copying-from/733f5367-32ce-4cb5-a7db-766e2f8711a5 - not helpful

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/copying-out-of-onenote-2013-has-strange-characters/e00f2fe0-6989-4d70-b53e-cab7474296c9 - not helpful


Several other web-pages but not related to OneNote.
UPDATE: This also happens with the web version of Microsoft Word.

Try to find which are these binary characters. OneNote has a tendency to add the VT character (vertical space) and convert space to non-breaking space. Question: How and from where in OneNote are you doing the copy?

Might be an issue with the clipboard tool used by your distro.
Check if the clipboard supports "paste as plain text" option.
In most systems, you can solve this issue by pasting using Ctrl + Shift + V (default shortcut for paste as plaintext).

I see you rep is 1 so you are new to the SuperUser stack exchange forum.  Welcome aboard.  Using Ctrl+Shift+v did solve this issue for me, so I'm marking this as the solution!
